# Layout that enlarges buttons for larger screens?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-3.0-honeycomb, tablet

When specifying the size of buttons and toolbars, I've been using the "device independent pixels" (dip) feature of the XML layout files. By using dips, I can specify the physical size of the GUI components, which is good for ensuring components are always readable and clickable for all screen sizes. For example, my app has a  horizontal toolbar that is about 50dip high at the top with several 40dipx40dip buttons along it.

However, buttons whose physical size is just big enough to see and click on for a small screen aren't very usable on tablets. For example, my toolbar will contain huge amounts of whitespace, the buttons are hard to see (as you tend to hold the tablet further away from your face) and the buttons are hard to click on in practice (as they are small proportional to the screen)

Are there any resolution independent approaches for dealing with this?

I know I can use "layout_weight" to stretch components so I can specify what percent of the screen to use but this is going to be really cumbersome for lots of buttons (also, my buttons need to be square) if I have to do this mostly manually. I can use different layout files for each device, but this is a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any resolution independent approaches for dealing with this?

Use dimension and drawable resources.

You haven't indicated how your buttons are "40dipx40dip".

If they are set that way via specific heights and widths, instead of having `40dip` in a layout or in a style, use `@dimen/toolbar_btn`. Then in `res/values/dimens.xml` define that to be `40dip` and in `res/values-large/dimens.xml` (or maybe `res/values-large-land/dimens.xml`) define that to be, say, `60dip`, or whatever works for you.

If the buttons are "40dipx40dip" because of images, then it's merely a matter of creating somewhat larger images for tablets and putting them in, say, `res/drawable-large-mdpi/` resource directory.

Comment: I'm setting the 40dip size in my layout file e.g. "<ImageButton android:layout_width="40dip" etc.". The "dimen" approach looks good but I wonder if there's a way for it to work out the new size for me (e.g. scale proportionally to the screen area), otherwise I'm going to have to tweak all the dimensions manually for each screen size. By the way, if I for example set my buttons to 60dip for the large layout, how do I know how many pixels to make the image file I place in the drawable folder.

Comment: @rebeccamaher: "otherwise I'm going to have to tweak all the dimensions manually for each screen size" -- yes. Considering that there are only four screen sizes, this would not seem to be an insurmountable task. "how do I know how many pixels to make the image file I place in the drawable folder" -- make them 50% bigger than whatever you are using for `40dip`, since 60 is 50% bigger than 40.

Comment: What I mean is that I'm assuming when you say an image should be displayed at 40x40dpi and Android goes to get the image file from the appropriate folder, how many pixels across should the file be so that no up or down scaling occurs? I'm confused about the relationship between dpi, pixels and the dpi folders.

Comment: @rebeccamaher: That is waaaaaaaaaaaaay beyond the scope of an SO comment. Try http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: OK, thanks. I thought it might just be something simple like multiplying two numbers together.